# After configuring Maven in Global tools of Jenkins, build step fails with error mvn not found

Tags: maven, jenkins

In Jenkins, I have configured Maven under Configure Global tools. 
Next, created a FreeStyle job and in the build step with execute shell. When I write mvn -v, the build fails with error mvn not found. But when I do the same exercise with JAVA_HOME, java -version , prints the correct version.

Comment: You have to add maven to your PATH variable

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue, I added a env variable under ( Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> ENV Variable). Added a new variable M2_HOME with value ( maven home on Jenkins machine)  and in the execute shell build step added a line PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin.

I am not sure if this is the best practice.